# Angular Compile Error rxjs when create new app

Tags: angular, rxjs

In First time when create angular 6 app gave me this error

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected. node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected. node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.

Comment: Did you create the app with `ng new`?

Comment: update your question with `package.json` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in packege.json file

"dependencies": {
"rxjs": "^6.0.0"
 }

must be

"dependencies": {
"rxjs": "6.0.0"
 }